# Signature for C-CEX API not accepted

Tags: python, rest, api, authentication

I'm attempting to authenticate myself with C-CEX.com, accessing a test [account's wallet information](https://c-cex.com/?id=api#getbalances).

I have meticulously followed [the documentation](https://c-cex.com/?id=api), and scoured the web for example code, but to no avail (aside from [this](https://github.com/salfter/PyCCEX/blob/master/PyCCEX.py) outdated library) - the result is always this:

```
>>>make_sign_and_request('getbalances')
{'success': False, 'result': None, 'message': 'INVALID_SIGNATURE'}
```

The entire process is further more complicated by the fact that there appears to be no Python example to be found, [and authentication is explained in PHP only](https://c-cex.com/?id=api#authentication) (on which my code below is based upon).

My signature function:

```
import requests
import time
import urllib
import hashlib
import hmac

# Keys for the test account
API_KEY = '7EAEBD233321AB48C8B5EAB58FF8849B'
API_SECRET = '139057C3B770C2DBCFCFFDD0D8A56E3F'


def make_sign_and_request(endpoint, **request_kwargs):
    req_kwargs = {'url': 'https://c-cex.com/t', 'headers': {}, 'files': {},
                  'data':  {}, 'params': {}, 'auth': {}, 'cookies': {},
                  'hooks': {}, 'json': {}}
    req_kwargs.update(request_kwargs)

    # Prepare Payload arguments
    nonce = str(int(time.time() * 1000))

    params = req_kwargs.pop('params')
    params['apikey'] = API_KEY
    params['nonce'] = nonce
    post_params = params
    post_params.update({'nonce': nonce, 'a': endpoint})
    url_encoded_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_params)
    url = req_kwargs['url'] + '/api.html?' + url_encoded_params
    print(url)
    # generate signature
    sig = hmac.new(API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), url.encode('utf-8'),
                   hashlib.sha512).digest()

    # update req_kwargs keys
    req_kwargs['headers'] = {'apisign': sig}
    req_kwargs['url'] = url
    return requests.request('GET', **req_kwargs)

print(make_sign_and_request('getbalances').json())
```

Now, I'm not a `PHP` wizard, but I'm quite confident I've duplicated the code in python quite accurately. Well, obviously not, otherwise the signaure would be accepted.

The api keys have been enabled and should work as expected.

The expected result should look something like this, [according to the documentation:](https://c-cex.com/?id=api#getbalances)

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Currency":"BTC","Balance":0.00000000,"Available":0,"Pending":0.00000000,"CryptoAddress":""}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved:

Adding a call to `hexdigest()` on the `hmac` object resolves the issue.